# Finding Klondike E Card 3 Pass Las Vegas Rules Solitiare for Ubuntu

Tags: software-sources

Due to the recent Internet explorer XP debacle, a friend enticed us to run on Ubuntu. My husband and I are in our late 70's.  He loves to play Klondike 3 Card 3 Pass Solitaire Las Vegas Rules.  I have been unable to find a version that will download onto Ubuntu.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Aisleriot has Klondike with a 3 card deal. Sorry, I'm not clear on what the Las Vegas rules are.

Comment: My understanding of the Vegas rules based on research is a single pass through the deck, not 3. Perhaps this varies by venue?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find that specific game, but there are many Solitaire alternatives for Ubuntu:

- [Solitaire](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/trusty/solitaire/)
- [Solitaire Egypt](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/trusty/solitaireegypt-eng/)
- [FreeCell Solitaire](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/aisleriot/)

And I'm sure there are even more outside Ubuntu's Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

Aisleriot has Klondike with a 3 card deal option. 3 Pass. I'm not sure what you mean by Las Vegas rules, but I suggest you try it and see if it fills the bill for you.